# Dynamic queryset for django admin based on GET parameter

Tags: django, django-admin, query-string

I would like to be able to modify the queryset in the changelist of a model admin based on url parameters.

For example given a list of a store's promotions I would like to have something like:

```
/admin/promotion/?success=4
```

where success of the promotion is a calculated business rule and not just a property of the model.

Is it possible?

Thanks!